# Angular-Meteor remote deployment

Tags: meteor, angular, deployment, openshift, ionic2

I have an Ionic2 (Angular2) mobile app that I am trying to connect to a remote Meteor Service.

I just deployed my Meteor App to OpenShift using [this guide](https://github.com/sachinbhutani/meteor-openshift). From the logs below, it looks successful.

> ```
> remote: Initiating MeteorShim
> remote: Starting NodeJS cartridge
> remote: *********** Meteor Environment ************
> remote: MONGO_URL IS: mongodb://127.10.247.2:27017/
> remote: ROOT_URL IS: http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com
> remote: PORT: 8080
> remote: BIND_IP: 127.10.247.1
> remote: DDP_URL: http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com:8000
> remote: ************ Starting NodeJS 0.10.40 SERVER  ************
> remote: Thu Sep 08 2016 09:43:15 GMT-0400 (EDT): Node server started on 127.10.247.1:8080 ...
> remote: Application is already running
> remote:
> remote:   - Using Node.js version 0.10.40, checking app URI ...
> remote:   - test URI = http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com/env
> remote: -------------------------
> remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
> remote: Activation status: success
> remote: Deployment completed with status: success
> ```

When I try the following, I get a timeout or 404.

```
http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com:3000/ (timeout)
http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com:8080/ (timeout)
http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com:8000/ (404)
```

When I run everything locally and the Ionic2 app accesses Meteor with the  default http://localhost:3000, it works.  So I changed the Ionic2 app to point to the remote server.

The Ionic2 App I have is trying to access it on http://mynodeapp-easyjobs.rhcloud.com:3000/8080/8000 unsuccessfully.

**Question**

How do I check if Meteor is running? What should I make my Ionic2 (Angular2) app point to?

Thanks

Comment: I am keen to use **OpenShift** because it is a free service if you have low usage. During development it is free, and I will only pay when it scales up when I use it for real. However, it does seem rather limited. Can anyone recommend something else?